# Симметричное шифрование php

Tags: php, шифрование, openssl

Подскажите, как реализовать симметричное шифрование на PHP?
Имеется текст, который нужно зашифровать, и ключ для шифрования, который представляет собой абракадабру длиной 128 байт, именно байт.

Ключ получается путем обмена ключами, открытыми, их подписями, дайджестами и т.д.

Comment: "как реализовать" - использовать [стандартные средства](http://php.net/manual/ru/refs.crypto.php)

Comment: Что именно не получается?

Comment: А не пытаетесь ли вы изобрести TLS?